# How to make preg_match_all return an empty array value if pattern not matched?

Tags: php, arrays, regex

Let's say we have the following data, with the code to match the pattern we'd like, in this case we're catching all numbers and unicode fractions.

```
$array = array('1 ½ cups','¼ cup','2 tablespoons', '½ cup', '1/3 cup',  '2 large', '1 ½ teaspoons', '2 tablespoons', 'Large egg', '1 teaspoon', '¼ teaspoon');

foreach($array as $arr){
    preg_match_all("/^(?:[\p{Pd}.\/\s-]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+/um", $arr, $output);

    foreach($output[0] as $data){
        $try[] = $data;
    }
}
```

If we `print_r($try)` we get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 ½
    [1] => ¼
    [2] => 2
    [3] => ½
    [4] => 1/3
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 1 ½
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 1
    [9] => ¼
)
```

There are 11 items in the array, one of them being complete text, *Large egg* in this example.

What I'm trying to do is make `preg_match_all` return an empty value for that iteration, so we'd get this instead:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1 ½
    [1] => ¼
    [2] => 2
    [3] => ½
    [4] => 1/3
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 1 ½
    [7] => 2
    [8] =>
    [9] => 1
    [10] => ¼
)
```

**What I've tried?**

I looked over the preg_match_all [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) but I wasn't able to find anything that could lead me to my answer, at this point I'm thinking it might have to be done over at the regex pattern, but I'm not sure at all at this point.

https://eval.in/885289

Comment: There is no way that I know of. You could check with `preg_match` if there was a match though and just use a conditional. https://eval.in/885295

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like each iteration can only return a maximum of one match, so `preg_match_all` with the inner foreach should not be needed. You can use `preg_match` and append a default blank value if there isn't a match.

```
foreach($array as $arr){
    preg_match("/^(?:[\p{Pd}.\/\s-]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟])+/um", $arr, $output);

    $try[] = $output[0] ?? '';

}
```

Comment: You all make me feel like quitting. I dislike all of your minds, with a passion. This is perfectly clean too.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Modify the pattern to this:

```
/^(?:[\p{Pd}.\/\s-]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟]|)+/um
```

Notice the "OR nothing" at the end.

```
<?php
$array = array('1 ½ cups','¼ cup','2 tablespoons', '½ cup', '1/3 cup',  '2 large', '1 ½ teaspoons', '2 tablespoons', 'Large egg', '1 teaspoon', '¼ teaspoon');

foreach($array as $arr){
    preg_match_all("/^(?:[\p{Pd}.\/\s-]*[\d↉½⅓⅔¼¾⅕⅖⅗⅘⅙⅚⅐⅛⅜⅝⅞⅑⅒⅟]|)+/um", $arr, $output);
    foreach($output[0] as $data){
        $try[] = $data;
    }
}
var_dump($try);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/hMW8l)

**Result:**

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "1 ½"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "¼"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "½"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "1/3"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [6]=>
  string(4) "1 ½"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [8]=>
  string(0) ""
  [9]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [10]=>
  string(2) "¼"
}
```

*Disclaimer: this looks like a dirty hack that is probably brittle, but it can get you in the right direction*

Comment: Aha, didn't even think about that, I need to stop and thinking about the problem first.. gosh. Thank you.

Comment: It's no problem. Remember to check the question as answered by marking the answer that helped you most (which I think should be Don't Panic's)

Comment: I agree, but I learned something new from both of you. Again, I appreciate it.